# Last element of Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, css-selectors

How can I check if a element with a certain class is the last of that class?

```
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="foo"></div> // I want to check if this is the last element of this class
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Comment: How are you identifying which instance we're talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The following will loop each div and say which div is last div

```
var count = $('div.foo').length;

$('div.foo').each(function(index){
  if(index == (count-1))
  {
    alert("this is last div" + index);
  }
});
```

---

like this you can get last element of the class

```
 var last_foo_div = $('div.foo:last');
```

or

```
   var foodivs= $('div.foo');
   var lastdiv  = foodivs.last();
```

Comment: This gets the last element, it doesn't check if an element we already have is the last element.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not sure how you are identifying this variable, lets say `$foo` is a jQuery object for that particular element.

You could do:

```
if (!$foo.next(".foo").length){
   //its the last foo
}
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2W6eT/*

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($('.foo').next('.foo').length == 0)
   alert("This is last Element")
```

Comment: This will just return the first "bar" element.